# Can be problems with different version of ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, cpanel

Now on my localhost I'm starting developing first simple web service using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.1 versions . But my hoster support only 2.3.14 version of ruby (becouse he is using Cpanel). Will a have problem with this? how to prevent them? Moreover, what difference is between 3.2.1 and 2.3.14, I meen gems etc? O it is better to start now developing using 2.3.14? what gems would not work in 2.3.14? will haml, sass, captcha and other gems work in old version?

Comment: Surely you mean version version 2.3.14 of *rails*, and not ruby. If your host has ruby v 2.3.14 that would mean that they're from the future and I must know who they are.

Comment: Better to change hoster rather than use deprecated rails version

Comment: sure, i wish to change hoster, but in our counrty (Belarus) we need that organisation services must be only in counrty datacenters, moreover not all hosters support rails... we are so far from now(((

Comment: @pavel I was being facetious ;-). Why can't you use a host outside of Belarus?

Comment: @Jon McIntosh because than i will be caught and go to prison( our laws are very strange and very strict...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you must use this host, I would suggest setting up your development environment to match.  A nice way to manage having multiple versions of ruby and try different gems is to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/).  This will allow you to manage multiple combinations of ruby (1.8.7, 1.9.2, ect) and multiple versions of rails and other associated gems.

As for the specific gems, both haml and sass will work with rails 2.3.
I am not sure what captcha gem you wish to use but from the popular [recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) gem readme:

> "Rails apps below 3.0 are no longer supported, but you can install an older release and view it’s README."

All in all you can make this setup work and you should not disrepair. There is a TON of example code out there on how to write and manage rails 2.3.
Good luck
/Salernost

Answer (score 0):

Maximum supported versions at this time are :

```
Ruby 1.8.7
RubyGems 1.8.25
Rails 2.3.18
```

Anything newer than that is a near guaranteed breakage and cPanel & WHM will be incapable of utilizing it in any way, shape, or form.

If you want to use any versions newer than this, then you will be **unable to use the cPanel & WHM interfaces or management tools for it** -- *they simply will not work*. You will then have to manually manage your RoR install by yourself through command line exclusively. None of it would fall under the scope of cPanel support.